# Approach to finding a function for a binary pattern

Tags: matrices, binary, inverse-problems

Below is a binary matrix of shape [64,63]. I want to find an equation to compute the values of this matrix as a function of rows and column indices. Are there any common strategies to attack such questions? Any idea for the result in this specific case?

**Background**: I am trying to solve the [64 coin impossible chessboard puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTJI_WuZSwE&t=1s). The problem below is a highly reduced version of that problem. I will not go into detail unless necessary, firstly because of spoilers, secondly because it is messy. I will just mention that I have obtained certain constraints for the subproblem, and then used a computer script to brute-force-search for a possible solution. If necessary, I can specify the constraints that the matrix possesses.

[image: Pattern]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Perhaps not too difficult because we can note that rows 4 to 7 are the complement of the "mirror at row 3-4"  of rows 0 to 3, rows 8 to 15 are the complement of the "mirror at row 7-8" of rows 0 to 7, and so on...

Comment: Well, not exactly the above... because some columns are "special"...